# What's the benefit of the Nothing constructor in Haskell?

Tags: functional-programming, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm not really sold on the `Nothing` constructor. It sounds like just another silent fail that's going to create headaches down the line. It seems much more useful to throw an error so I'll have a clue what's happening.

Why am I wrong here?

Comment: There are a number of questions (both here and on SO) concerning the advantages of option types. How does your question differ from all of them?

Comment: I don't know if it is. I didn't couldn't find any threads that answered my question.

Comment: @Hex Bob-omb: You throw an error when you encounter one. Nothing indicates one possible result of a partial function. Nothing does not indicate an error but the correct result of a computation.

Comment: @HexBob-omb http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=maybe and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maybe for starters. There are probably other searches that yield even more.

Comment: I wouldn't really say that `Nothing` is a *silent* fail. Unlike `null` in other languages, functions that may return `Nothing` will say so in their type and the type system will force you to handle the possibility of `Nothing` in some way.

Comment: @Giorgio How does any of what you just said contradict what I said?

Comment: @sepp2k: Excuse me, I have misread your comment (would instead of wouldn't). I will correct my comment.

Comment: I agree with sepp2k. Just to add a few ideas: Languages that support option types also support exceptions to signal real errors. `Nothing` indicates the successful computation of a result. Example: if you look up a customer in a database you return `Nothing` if you do not find the customer, you throw an exception if there is not database connection.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to Telastyn's answer:

`Maybe` never "silently fails". In contrast to null, which might be what the OP's is comparing it to, a Haskell function which can return `Nothing` must explicitly do so in its type.

For comparison: a method returning `String` in Java might return a String or null, and you cannot tell just by looking at its type:

```
public String myFunc(int x) { /* do something, might return null! */ }
```

In Haskell a function which returns a `String` has a type similar to this:

```
myFunc :: Int -> String
```

You know it cannot return `Nothing`, because if it did, its type would be:

```
myFunc :: Int -> Maybe String
```

This means `Nothing` can never sneak up on you and "cause headaches down the line"!

Answer (score 13):

> Why am I wrong here?

Because a lack of value is not *always* indicative of an error.

Comment: Exactly (+1). Error means: I do not know how to continue the computation. Nothing means: I have successfully completed the computation and determined that there is no result for the given inputs.